# Get call in Ruby script without using AWS SDK Library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to make an GET request in Ruby using an AWS signature. I have the Access key and Secret key.

Authorization details with aws signature need to pass
in authorization i need to pass secret key and access key and in advance service name, can some one help me what i need to change

Below is my sample code:

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeDhcpOptions&Version=2016-11-15&DhcpOptionsId=dopt-ee2bb494")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
#request["X-Amz-Date"] = "20201215T042546Z"
#request["Authorization"] = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIA4DK4ETWGHN3N5ANE/20201215/us-east-1/ec2/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=d60b6b08081dc2ca499311d30a6b47d0c28ce24cad9dc5176895003302d1b03a"

response = https.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Although this does not directly answer your question, the modern Rubyist uses higher-level HTTP tools like https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty, https://github.com/lostisland/faraday or https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus. Using net/http directly is an unfortunate pain in the bum.

Comment: @dbugger: script is not working when i run in any  IDE, every time i need to change 'X-Amz-Date' and 'Authorization' values from postman code.

Comment: i tried below code to generate aws signature getting values in unsupported language

Comment: require 'openssl'
def getSignatureKey key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName
    kDate = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', "AWS4" + key, dateStamp)
    kRegion = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kDate, regionName)
    kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', kService, "aws4_request")

    kSigning
end

crypt=getSignatureKey('JW1Nwde0w+7MMghGpAWw/V0su/UG+DW/sTZr5ro2','20201215', 'us-east-1', 'ec2')
#puts crypt